# Same page is loading when clicking pagination in DataTable PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

When I click page number in DataTable, it is not moving to next page instead it loads the whole page again.

But if I click the DataTable sorting button and again I click the pagination page number, the DataTable is working fine. Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
</style>
  <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
  <section class="bg-gray-7">
    <div class="breadcrumbs-custom box-transform-wrap context-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 class="breadcrumbs-custom-title">Sailing Schedules</h3>
        <div class="breadcrumbs-custom-decor"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-transform" style="background-image: url(images/bg-typography.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="breadcrumbs-custom-path">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Sailing Schedule</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

<br>
<br>
<div class="container">

<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  // Include config file
  require 'config.php';

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM long_sched";
  if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      echo "<table class='table-custom table-custom-primary' id ='long_schd_table'>";
      echo "<thead>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>Service Name</th>";
      echo "<th>Description</th>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</thead>";
      echo "<tbody>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href=http://localhost/permatest/". $row['long_filepath'] . " target='_self' download>".$row['long_service']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['long_desc'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</tbody>";                            
      echo "</table>";
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
      echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
    } else {
      echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute ".$sql." " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
?>

</div>
</section>
<br>
<br>

<?php include 'off_footer.php'; ?>

<script>
  $('#long_schd_table').DataTable({});
</script>
```

The above code is giving this error but in my console I didn't get any error information.

Comment: Hi bro~ I think your code some of them is missing... can you edit your question again?

Comment: hi bro,i edited the code and submitted full code. can u help me to solve this issue.

Comment: why dont you use datatable properly, use an ajax to load data , dont loop through yourself, and then use serverside for pagination and search and ordering

Comment: ok bro.i will try that.But why this error is happening can u explain it. I am using normal datatable script.

Comment: Hi @AhmedSunny i tried using the  server side processing again i am getting the same issue...
the below one is my url
http://perma.sg/sailing_shed.php.

Comment: @Bharathkumar this looks fine, the pagination, ordering, search and lenght works,
its not reloading same page